# How could I swap object A properties for object B properties in DBContext?

Tags: entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I have two objects of same Type and I want to swap A for B. Instead of using this:

```
var tmp = A.prop1; 
A.prop1 = B.prop1; 
B.prop1 = tmp; .... 
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Is there any faster way?

Comment: This already is a blink of an eye, pretty useless to optimize it. Or do you mean faster as in less code? Maybe you should show the bigger picture, I feel that something else than swapping may be appropriate.

Comment: At StackOverflow, if you are interested in getting answers at all, you really have to be quick to respond to comments like the one above. You question is practically forgotten by now.